# Disable File Browsing Chrome/Firefox

Tags: remote-desktop-services, firefox, google-chrome, xenapp, windows-terminal-services

Want to publish Firefox or Chrome in a XenApp/RDS environment. However, I can't find any central way to disable file browsing (ie. type c:\ in address bar). In fact, I can't find any great way in general to do this at all with these browsers. This leaves me with having to use IE, which I'd really rather not do as the apps they're accessing really recommend using Firefox or Chrome.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: It most likely is not possible, short of you  building some kind of patch and re-compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Chrome policies to disable file browsing. See https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en for more details about how to use Group Policy to configure policies for Chrome.

For file browsing in particular, you probably want to set AllowFileSelectionDialogs to "disabled", and to add "file://" to the URL blacklist. See:

http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AllowFileSelectionDialogs
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#URLBlacklist